# Obtaining value from 2nd Row Field from selected row in first row

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am looking to obtain the corresponding value from the 1st-row field in a pivot table when a value in the 2nd-row field is selected.

I have a two "row" pivot table with worksheet names in the first row and cell references in the second.

[image: Pivot-Table Example]

I am planning on using this information to create hyperlink actions. What I am struggling to get however is the corresponding sheet name from row1 when a cell reference in row2 is selected.

In the above example table, I can capture the cell reference (for example A$3$) when it is selected, but I can't figure out how to get the worksheet data (in this example Sheet3)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what happens if the user selects **$B$13**?

Comment: I've tried experimenting with getpivotdata, and getting the row value of the clicked item, but can't seem to find a way to then navigate to the same point down the 1st row. As for the selection - right now nothing happens - what's supposed to happen once I can get the missing piece is that the user will be hyperlinked to the corresponding sheet and cell reference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best answer, but for me, elegant enough:

```
IIf(IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0, -1)), Target.Offset(0, -1).End(xlUp).Value, Target.Offset(0, -1).Value)
```

This will check the cell in the previous column for a value and return it if there is one, otherwise it will return the value in the first non-empty cell directly above it.